# How to check if ip forwarding is enabled

Tags: networking, server, iptables, ufw

i have 2 vps services from 2 diffrent providers and i want to use iptables for prerouting .
i can do it easily on one but cant do it on the other one , i almost read all articles and tried them but nothing worked for me . any idea where to check?
another thing there is a diffrence between two servers , the one which wont do ip forward , has an additional startup service call networking.service .

EDIT (from the comment, so we can read it): here are my iptables rules:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
DNAT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:22 to:158.58.185.249
DNAT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 to:91.107.191.135

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
MASQUERADE all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: What version or versions of Ubuntu are being used?

Comment: To check if ip forwarding is enabled do: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. Otherwise we need more information, such as your iptables rule set.

Comment: ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: @PouriaSh did you check the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` yet?  That will determine if forwarding is enabled at the network card level and kernel level, and is a requisite for actual NAT to function

Comment: @ThomasWard yes ive checked and its enabled . i also put sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 on my first line on iptables service . i'll be glad if anyone can check my server personally .

Comment: @PouriaSh when adding content that is comman dline and multline, add it as an edit to your post in the future please.